# Answer Diversity Rewarded or Frowned Upon?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

Is diversity in answers really allowed?

On some of my replies to questions on SO, my intent is to provide an alternate line of thinking; a different path to take. For sometimes in development there are more than one way resolve an issue that may not always direclty answer the question. The hope is to provide an insight on a side topic. Such topic may not the answer current question, but could help *someone*, if not the originator of the question with an alternate line of thought. *Isn’t that what a community is for…to provide all possible solutions?*

---

With that backdrop I find myself being targeted and heavily critiqued for some of my, to quote one of the someone’s response

> **Another** not really relevant answer”

*Emphasis mine*.

In a span of an hour I became a target of multiple people who began to enumerate my responses and pulled out the worst of the worst (with a couple exceptions) to expose to the world the ones they felt broken some cardinal rule. They took one answer, *which I replied two almost two years ago*, (where it was marked as answer) and made it a comment (though nobody else answered or helped the OP) and told me and I quote

> “Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.”

Wow…link rot? The blog linked to is from Microsoft’s SQL server team blog! The article is not a simple how to, but a laundry list of things to try.

---

I get that my posts will be marked down and that to me is a learning experience; but isn’t it better to attempt an answer than not provide one at all?

Comment: Any chance you can summarize in a TLDR version?  Interestingly, your posts that are around 100 words both have positive scores.  Your posts with over 200 words have negative scores.  This post has 809...

Comment: Any chance of a movie version?

Comment: I up voted you twice today, OmegaMan. Way to make unfounded accusations. Now I've also down voted you twice today.

Comment: As for the answers in question being *thin*, that is an understatement. Multiple of the answers I marked had *nothing* to do with their questions.

Comment: "Isn’t that what a community is for…to provide all possible solutions?" This is a notion you need to disabuse yourself of and quickly. We are not interested in *all possible solutions.* We are interested in the *best possible solution.* And by definition, a solution that doesn't even attempt to address the actual question is not going to be the best possible solution.

Comment: +1 for the entertaining metaphors!

Comment: *Brevity is the soul of wit.*  Also, you can spam and be considered a spammer without actually making a single dime off of what you are promoting.

Comment: @Won't Is there any irony in the fact that you edited that comment to add to it? ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - There is often no best solution for every circumstance.  A solution that doesn't apply to the OP's situation but could reasonably apply to that of people reading it can have its place.  Though my guess is you wouldn't place the answers in question even into that category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned, most of your post is kind of a rant (venting, as you called it), so I'll respond to the main point:

> Is diversity in answers really allowed?

Of course!  Having a variety of approches to reach a solution is great.  Bring on the diversity.

**But, the common denominator among these approaches is that they need to be *good* answers**.  There are so many descriptions of "*What is a good answer?*" on this website (here on meta, on the blog, in the faq, etc) that I'm not going to go into what that entails.

For instance your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720735/when-to-use-the-lock-thread-in-c/8720778#8720778) is great.  It is much, much better than the first revision, where you just linked to your blog.  You give a brief explanation and an example.

On the other hand, this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720735/when-to-use-the-lock-thread-in-c/8720936#8720936) to the same question was also great, even though it takes a completely different approach (explaining, in laymens terms, the nature of the problem and how it can be solved).

If that is not diversity in answers being viewed *very favorably by the community* (indicated by the upvotes on both answers), I don't know what is.

It seems like you're frustrated by some negative experiences you've had.  *Learn from those experiences*; try not to see them as a personal attack, but as *an opportunity to improve your future posts*.  If someone took the time to go through your answers and judge them, learn from that as well.

Comment: An excellent answer. Side note: My comments on those answers, especially the old ones, were basically meant for the OP and myself. Aside from the mod who handled my flag, no one else would have known of them were it not for this question.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew.  I figured as much.  Honestly, it sounds like you were giving the OP some much needed guidance on what is acceptable in the community, and they just took it personally.